# Driving School rewards in GT Sport

Tags: gran-turismo-sport

The [Driving School](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gran-turismo-sport/Driving_School) in Gran Turismo Sport (formerly known as license tests) gives you various rewards...

- Money, miles and XP based on what medal you achieve (gold, silver, bronze)
- Every 8 passed tests (bronze or higher) you get a free car

Is there any final reward for getting a gold medal in every single test? Of course you get more money, miles and XP from the gold medals directly, but what happens if you complete the Driving School with all gold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a Nissan GTR Safety car.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you provide a source for this information such as a wiki link, personal experience, screenshot, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Makasuro is right: You really get a Nissan GT-R SC, but in addition here's the proof...

[image]

[image]